# Query and Update json objects based on their keys using sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i have stored a json object(type->jsonb) in my postgres DB, need to Query and Update json based on key using sequelize, i could not found a way for this, any ideas??

Comment: Never tried but can try following the link - https://www.compose.com/articles/is-postgresql-your-next-json-database/ with raw queries to filter result and update it once result is fetched

Comment: no issuses in raw queries, but need ORM mapping and function calls